# Will flat file database work with relation between two columns?

Tags: php, database

Database.txt

```
    Field1-Field2
    Field3-Field4
    Field1-Field2
    Field1-Field2
```

[Saved the above data into a txt file from a html form]

```
    **www.site.com/?type=Field1** should output **Field2**
    **www.site.com/?type=Field3** should output **Field4**
    ....... and so on
```

I want to check all the Field1’s for the type and if it is found,  I want to display Field2. What would be the best way to store data for this need? How do I check the first column for a string and display it's corresponding string? All in PHP.

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to use a real rdbm

Comment: @Dagon That would be an overkill for this little application with no more than 20 records/lines. Otherwise I'm already a mysql user.

Comment: i use a table for 1 record, still easier to maintain than a txt file -you call :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it:

Use [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) to read the contents of the file.

[`explode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) on a newline to get an array consisting of the lines in your text file.

Loop through your array and explode again, this time on a dash.

Check the first exploded value and if it matches, output the second exploded value and exit your script.  If it doesn't match, continue until you find a match or end your loop.

```
<?php

$data = file_get_contents('/path/to/file');

$lines = explode("\n", $data);

foreach ($lines as $line)
{
    list($foo, $bar) = explode('-', $line);

    if ($foo == $_GET['type'])
    {
        echo $bar;
        // Terminate script, perhaps?
    }
}

echo 'No matches found';

?>
```

Comment: Thanks, It worked perfectly, list() did the trick to my existing code.

Comment: Any idea on how to use with json instead?